# Custom listview footer in my custom adapter?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I'm curious if I can create a footer for my custom  listview in my arrayAdapter class?

What I'm hoping to get out of this footer are a subtotal, tax, and total textview that will automatically sum and do "math" on my listview's "Order" when new items are applied to it.

Would doing it in the arrayAdapter be the best approach? Or should I do it inside the fragment?

I was trying to do it inside the fragment but was running into difficulty with getting data from the row's of the listview.

Just to clarify; the listview is inside its own fragment, it will be pretty alone aside from the textviews I mentioned above.

If in the fragment, which part of the lifecycle should I put it in? I haven't set up onClickListeners just yet, but I feel putting everything in onCreateView() would be incorrect since I will be adding things dynamically.

Edit: The problem I was having while doing it in my fragment was that the getListviewChildren was returning empty; I'm assuming cause I was using it in my onCreateView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of implementing it yourself in the adapter you can use ListView's own implementaion for a footer view. just call addFooterView on the list and pass it the view you want as a footer.

```
 ListView listView = .. //create your list, or inflate it from xml...
 View footerView = ... //create your view, or inflate it from xml...
 listView.addFooterView(footerView);
 listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

2 things you should know though: It is best to call this method before using setAdapter on the list, because on all but the latest version of android calling it after will not have any affect. Another thing is that doing so is implemented by wrapping your adapter inside another adapter, so after using this you cannot use getAdapter() to get your original adapter.

For more info go to: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29

Comment: Sounds good; even though GetAdapter won't be giving my original adapter would I still be able to use in notifyDataSetChanged() ? How will I get the information from my listview and put it in my footer since it needs to update everytime I call notifyDataSetChanged ?

Comment: you can still use notifyDataSetChanged(), either keep a reference to your original adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged() on it, or you can even do it with the adapter getAdapter() returns to you, if I am not mistaken this will also work. To modify the data in the footer you can keep a reference to the footerView and modify the data there every time you want to call notifyDataSetChanged(). I would suggest to create a method, let's say updateData(), and inside it do 2 things: call notifyDataSetChanged() on your original adapter and also do whatever you need with your footerView. Good luck!